# redirect to maintainence page... how to choose pages

Tags: php, .htaccess

so i've manage to redirect all urls to a specific page for maintenance. That works ok.
My problem is that i don't want all urls to go to maintenance... just two..

How do i redirect when a user click the following url's (including subfolder,etc...):

```
http://www.mysite.com/discography/
http://www.mysite.com/songbook/
```

this is my code that works ok (i've allowed my localhost ip address and the ip address on my live site to bypass the rules):

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^99\.999\.99\.999
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^0\.0\.0\.0
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /maintenance.php [R=307,L]
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply adjust the `RewriteCond` that matches the URI accordingly:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(discography|songbook)/ [NC]
```